# Is this algorithm with three nested loops O(m*n) or O(m*n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, nested-loops

i'm doing a code challenge for funzies and trying to determine the time complexity of my solution. it's been a minute since college so i want to confirm i'm doing this analysis correctly. here's the code (i've generalized it as best i can so that the specifics of the actual problem are irrelevant, so it's more pseudo-code). the file is a basic text file with strings separated by new lines. every line is the same length, so it can be conceptualized as a grid. in this analysis, let m=#lines (rows) and n=#characters per line (columns).

```
currRow = 0
for line in file:
    for match in re.finditer(r"\d+", line):
        for i in range(match.start(), match.end()):
            print(currRow, i) // placeholder, the actual logic i'm checking here is irrelevant
    currRow += 1
```

i'm trying to determine if the time complexity is O(m*n) or O(m*n<sup>2</sup>)

the outermost loop iterates m times, so that part is easy to figure out. i'm puzzling over the two inner-most loops and their relationship. the regex i'm using is greedy, so it will search for the longest substrings of digits possible (e.g. 123abc4567 would only return matches of 123 and 4567, not smaller sub matches such as 23 or 56). still, taken completely separately, it's easy to see that each loop *could* grow with respect to n (in the first loop's case, you could still have up to n/2 matches, for the second loop you could have a single match and thus have to run through every index in the string). and since they're nested, that could imply a complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>). but my intuition tells me that these loops are interrelated and in fact when taken as a whole are constrained by O(n) and i can't think of a situation in which n^2 operations would actually take place.

here's how i figure it: the outer loop iterates over all the matches, so #matches operations. the inner loop operates on every index within each. but due to the greedy regex, the largest these matches could be is (n / #matches), since the substrings must have their own characters. thus, the combined complexity of these loops could be categorized as #matches * (n / #matches) = n. and even if we assume #matches is constrained by (can't have more matches than characters) we could state O(n) * O(n/n) which is still O(n), asymptotically.

is this correct? or is my intuition mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

#### Your intuition is correct.

If the number of matches is `k`, and the matches have lengths `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, ..., `n_k` respectively, then the complexity of

```py
for match in matches:
    for i in range(match.start(), match.end()):
        do_one_operation()
```

is the sum `n1 + n2 + ... + n_k`.

And assuming the matches do not overlap (you have to justify this!!), this sum is at most equal to the number of characters in the line.

However, there are a few caveats.

#### Complexity of `re.finditer`

When you call function `re.finditer` on `line`, this function will internally perform a loop over the line to find the matches. This loop is obviously at least O(n), but perhaps it's even more. You have to look at the documentation of `re.finditer` to make sure.

Happily, `re.finditer` is only called once on the whole line, before the `for match in ...` loop actually starts, so your total complexity will be `O(m * ((complexity of finditer) + complexity of inner loop))`. If the complexity of `finditer` is O(n^2), then your total complexity will be O(m n^2) even if the inner loop is only O(n).

#### Complexity of what you do inside the inner loop

You wrote:

```py
print(currRow, i) // placeholder, the actual logic i'm checking here is irrelevant
```

It's actually relevant. The only thing you have proven so far is that the operation written here will be executed O(m n) times. But if this operation itself has a complexity larger than O(1), then the total complexity of your code will be larger than O(m n).

Note that when expression complexity we typically announce what we're counting. The complexity is the number of <the operation we're counting>. When talking about the complexity of comparison sorts, we typically count the number of comparisons. If you don't explicitly specify the operation that you're counting, then the reader will assume that the operation you're counting is somewhat "elementary", but if actually the operation perform in your inner loop is a slow operation (such as itself containing a loop), then saying that your code has complexity O(m n) is deceiving.

Comment: thank you for the response! answering your concerns in order:
1. the fact that matches don't overlap is a stipulation of the problem itself, as well as assured by the regex '/d+' i believe.
2. yeah i should've accounted for finditer, i glossed over it since it wasn't my implementation but you're right. from what i can tell regex matching can be done in O(n) and I assume this is an optimal implementation, but haven't found that stated directly.
3. yes by 'is irrelevant' what i meant more precisely is that the logic in the inner loop is done in constant time (comparison, access list, etc.)

Comment: but thank you for confirming my intuition! like i said i'm very out of practice with algorithmic analysis and i wrote this out while solving a coding challenge and got to thinking about the time complexity... i was pretty sure it couldn't be O(n^2) in the inner loops but was struggling to justify why!

Comment: With this regular expression, with almost all engines, it will be linear. And the next match always starts after the last one. But there is a subset of regular expressions that  can take exponential time in many engines if they find no match. An example is `r"(a|aa)*b"` on a long string of `aaa...` with no `b`.